# Getting a particular row's attribute value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this function which I believe is following this process:

```
function verify(){
    $.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
                verified = $(data).find("marker").eq(-1).attr('verification');
        });
}
```

1. Get data from php file/db
2. In the db, find the table "marker"
3. Find the last record in the table marker
4. Assign the value of the 'verification' column to the variable verified

This is doing what I want (kind of) but I need to be able to specify what record to get the 'verification' value from, but not by it's position in the table (as more records will be added and the above will just get the last record regardless). Is there another method that is kind of like `.eq(x)` but will allow me to specifically select a record based on another attr in that record.

eg. Say I want to find the verification value for record 1 through an event listener, and then find the verification value for record 6 through a different event listener.

I have a variable which can distinguish what row I want to get, but how can I incorporate this into the statement above. (i'm thinking instead of `.eq(-1)`

Comment: Why do you request multiple rows and return XML when you only want to get a single string? Pass the ID(primary key) of the desired row as parameter to the PHP-file and simply return the value of the verification-column with the particular ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` which can contain as many conditions as you need.

```
$.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
          var myVariable = $(data).find("marker").filter(function(elementIndex, element){
                return $(this).attr('someOtherAttribute') === 'valueWanted';
          }).attr('verification');
});
```

Since I'm really not sure what the data looks like or what attribute you need the above is only a guess at how you would need to implement

See [**filter() API docs**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)